# My regex works in regex101.com sandbox but not in actual javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I created regex to cut some part out of sourcecode.

```
/SRC_START\n([\s\S]*?)\n\/\/SRC_END/i
```

I tested it on [regex101.com where it appears to work](https://regex101.com/r/pC5aW5/1).

But it doesn't work in my console:

```
"ddd\
//SRC_START\
  function bounce(objectA, objectB) {} \
  \
//SRC_END\
  return bounce;\
})".match(/SRC_START\n([\s\S]*?)\n\/\/SRC_END/i)
```

As you can see I verbatim copied the data from myregex101 snippet. The result I get is `null`.

Comment: Are you sure there are no CR symbols? Try replacing `\n` with `\r?\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input string is not same as what you have on regex101.

Declare your input as:

```
var str = 'ddd\n//SRC_START\n  function bounce(objectA, objectB) {} \n\n//SRC_END\n  return bounce;\n})\n';
```

Then doing this:

```
var re = /SRC_START\n([\s\S]*?)\n\/\/SRC_END/i;
var m = str.match(re);
```

Will give this match array:

```
["SRC_START
  function bounce(objectA, objectB) {} 

//SRC_END", "  function bounce(objectA, objectB) {} 
"]
```

For doing everything inline in console do:

```
"ddd\n\
//SRC_START\n\
  function bounce(objectA, objectB) {}\n \
  \
//SRC_END\n\
  return bounce;\n\
})".match(/SRC_START\n([\s\S]*?)\n\s*\/\/SRC_END/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and multiline `m` flag on regex.

```js
var matches = `ddd
//SRC_START
  function bounce(objectA, objectB) {}

//SRC_END
  return bounce;
})`.match(/SRC_START\n([\s\S]*?)\n\/\/SRC_END/im);

console.log(matches);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(matches, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code, I see, is the source string is not properly escaped.

```js
// the src must be properly escaped
var src = "ddd\n"+
"//SRC_START\n"+
" function bounce(objectA, objectB) {} \n"+
"\n"+
"//SRC_END\n"+
" return bounce;\n"+
"})\n"+
"";
var match = src.match(/SRC_START\n([\s\S]*?)\n\/\/SRC_END/i);
alert("WHOLE MATCH:\n" + match[0] + "\n\nCAPTURED GROUP:\n" + match[1]);
```